# Как оптимизировать Unity проект для Samsung Gear VR так, чтобы при повороте головой ничего не тормозило (высокополигональных моделей нет)?

Tags: c#, unity3d, mobile-development, vr

Все сиденья - на простейшие элементы (примерно 270 полигонов на сиденье x 50 штук в зале = 13500 полигонов). Остальное окружение составляют кубы с наложенными на них текстурами, но камера показывает 11 миллионов полигонов. Свет запечён. Работает Batching. С чем это может быть связано и как это можно исправить?

[image: На фото: 37 миллионов полигонов]

Comment: информация со скрина: setPass calls : 10852 (оно же DrawCalls) то есть как правильно указали в ответе, батчинг не работает

Comment: Ещё добавить [Occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) заметно увеличит ФПС для вашего проекта.

Answer (score 1):

[Батчинг не работает](https://pasteboard.co/Hmlq74C.png).(для Gear VR желательно держать batch в пределах 100. т.е. 38081=>100 )
Откройте окно [профайла](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Profiler.html) и посмотрите причину такого количества отрисовок.
(первоночальное профилирование лучше провести в редактор, дальше только на устройстве)

- На вскидку  - перевести геометрию в статичную.
- После запекания отключить весь свет.
- Убедиться что используются общие материалы.

Comment: Ещё добавить [Occlusion culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) заметно увеличит ФПС для его проекта.

Comment: occlussion culling, Lod, mip maps и вагон других вещей) но понять причину только через профайл)